# Jets test any(HTML) - is this possible?

Tags: jestjs

I am checking that a component returned as expected by looking at the props it was called with.

Since updating some of my code, I now have a new key of `children` which has a value that is HTML.

How can I add the HTML to the expected props without actually specifying the explicit HTML? I don't care what the content of the HTML is (that's for later tests) but I want to check it was called correctly.

```
  const defaultProps = {
    title: "Foo",
    contentLoaded: true,
    type: center,
    passedFunc: expect.any(Function),
    id: "id-1234",
    children: expect.any(HTML) // what goes here?
  };

  it("should render the component", () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(ChildComponent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({ type: center, ...defaultProps }),
      {}
    );
  });
```

**What goes in the `children` default prop to allow my test to pass, where `children` is HTML?**

Comment: you can not use any, instead of that you can use expect.stringContaining(HTML)

Comment: `expect.stringContaining(HTML)` isn't valid code. What is the value of `HTML`?

Comment: if you don't care about content then you can use expect.anything()

Answer (score 0):

Let me give example if this can be helpful to you

```
const defaultProps = {
  title: "XXX",
  contentLoaded: true,
  type: "center",
  passedFunc: expect.any(Function),
  id: "id-1234",
  children: expect.anything()
};

it("render component", () => {
  render(<MyComponent />);
  expect(ChildComponent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({ type: "center", ...defaultProps }),
    {}
  );
});
```

Hope this will help you.